# Python convert a string in to its actual Boolean value?

Tags: python, boolean, logic

I have a function that returns a string that can be interpreted as a Boolean

```
def foo():
    return "not(True and False)"
```

How can I return the actual Boolean value, in this case True?

Comment: Yes. I want not(True) to be False, (True or False) to be True. Whatever the results would be If the quotes would not be there.

Comment: I think eval() will probably already work, have you tried using this function?

Comment: Why does your function have such a strange return value? The best approach is likely to change the function.

Comment: Python 3, I want to return the actual Boolean value.

Comment: _I have a function that returns a string that can be interpreted as a Boolean_ What, why?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `eval`:

```
def foo():
    return eval("not(True and False)")
```

Even tho it is virtually the only solution, but it is still not safe.

Check this [link](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) for why it is not safe.